# Use jQuery to change page title with the value retrieved from the external page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change page title using value retrieved from the div on the external page. All files are local, in the same folder, or it will be under same domain once uploaded.

This is html on the external page (settings.html):

```
<div id="clientName">Some Company</div>
```

I'm using `.load` function to get the content of that div from different page (index.html):

```
$('title').load('settings.html #clientName');
```

Once executed page title is changed into file path to settings.html page (file://blahblah) instead "Some Company". But all works fine if I try to load same content into div, like this:

```
$('div.test').load('settings.html #clientName');
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Klikerko

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I don't want to start discussion about practicality of the code above. I'm aware that there are better ways to do this but, this is demo/test project that will be most likely run from the local machine without local server running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this needs to be done asynchronously with a callback.

```
$('<div/>').load('settings.html #clientName', function(response, status, xhr) {
    $("title").text($(this).text());
    //or
    //document.title = $(this).text();
});
```

`document.title = $('<div/>'). ...` won't work in a month of Sundays. You can't assign a jQuery object as if it was text.

If @Magicmarkker is right about IE not playing with `$("title")...`, then use `document.title = $(this).text()`.

Comment: If that's what's served, that's what you will get. - try one of my suggested alternatives. `response` must be the whole document before the fragment is extracted.

Comment: Thanks! Both `$("title").text($(this).text());' and `document.title = $(this).text();' updated the title correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don'y use `$('title')` IE doesn't support it too well. Instead use `document.title = 'whatever';` The below will work

```
document.title = $('<div/>').load('settings.html #clientName');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use jQuery for that. Just use good ol'

```
document.title = $('<div/>').load('settings.html #clientName');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. When I use this code page title gets updated to `[object Object]`